# Insert picture in microsoft office word .docx

Tags: c#, docx

I have picture in pictureBox. I want to insert it in docx. How can i do so?

I have used the follwing code to do so but it's not working. How can i Replace in docx "picture" on image?

```
  ReplaceWordStub("{picture}", pictureBox.Image, wordDocument);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find specific text and replace with Image file in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456792/find-specific-text-and-replace-with-image-file-in-ms-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bad code,but it's working.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;



 var wordApp = new Word.Application();
            wordApp.Visible = false;
        try
        {

            var wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(TemplateFileName);
            ReplaceWordStub("{ILL}", dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), wordDocument);
            pictureBoxTgt.Image.Save(@"C:\Template\1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            string fileName = @"C:\Template\1.jpg";
            Object oMissed = wordDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range; 
            Object oLinkToFile = false;  
            Object oSaveWithDocument = true;
            wordDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fileName, ref oLinkToFile, ref oSaveWithDocument, ref oMissed);
            wordDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\Result\" + name +  ".doc");
            wordDocument.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        }
        finally
        {
            wordApp.Quit();
        }
        File.Delete(@"C:\Template\1.jpg");
```